# Progressive Web App (PWA) Displays Only One Screenshot During Installation

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I'm facing an issue with my Progressive Web App (PWA) manifest where only one screenshot is displayed during installation, even though I've defined multiple screenshots with different form factors.

As I have added two narrow and two wide images, I should see at least two screenshots. Additionally, when I refresh the page and click on the install button, I notice the same screenshot getting added each time. Initially, there is one screenshot, and after a refresh, two screenshots with the same image appear. After another refresh, I see three screenshots with the same image.

Here's a snippet of my manifest:

```
 manifest: {
        "name": "Decker",
        "short_name": "Decker",
        "description": "Decker is a...",
        "icons": [
          {
            "src": "/favicons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable"
          },
          {
            "src": "/favicons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
          },
          {
            "src": "/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png",
            "sizes": "180x180",
            "type": "image/png"
          },
          {
            "src": "/favicons/favicon-32x32.png",
            "sizes": "32x32",
            "type": "image/png"
          },
          {
            "src": "/favicons/favicon-16x16.png",
            "sizes": "16x16",
            "type": "image/png"
          }
        ],
        "start_url": "/",
        "display": "standalone",
        "background_color": "#fcfefc",
        "theme_color": "#fcfefc",
        screenshots: [{ src: "/screenshots/decker_cards_page.png", form_factor: "narrow", sizes: "462x822", "type": "image/png", label: "cards page" }, { src: "/screenshots/fullscreen_card_view.png", form_factor: "narrow", sizes: "462x820", "type": "image/png", label: "fullscreen card view" }, , { src: "/screenshots/windows_cards_page.png", form_factor: "wide", sizes: "1920x933", "type": "image/png", label: "cards page " }, { src: "/screenshots/windows_full_screen_view.png", form_factor: "wide", sizes: "1920x936", "type": "image/png", label: "fullscreen card view" }],

      }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be in the sizes of pictures. You have the following sizes: 462x822,  462x820, 1920x933, 1920x936. So, if you want to have two or more screenshots for wide screens, all related pictures should be the same size - 1920x933 (or 1920x936)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now, I have changed my images to the same sizes. For large screens, I added three images with a size of 960x466, and for small screens, I added three images with a size of 345x615. Now, I can see all three images as expected.

However, there is still one more problem. When I refresh the page, I see that the images get repeated. For example, when the page loads, I see three screenshots. If I refresh, I see six images repeating the first three. If I refresh again, I see nine, and it continues. Why is this happening?

Comment: I see. I got the same issue now now. But I have 5 pictures for each form factor. I guess (didn't check yet) that I have to reduce amount of pictures. But you said that you have only 6 pictures.

I would recommend to try to reduce the number of pictures for some form factor. Then, we will see what to do